# length function in mysql

Tags: mysqli, mysql-error-1064

I try that:

```
SELECT length(users) as users_len,
       auto_reply_users 
FROM forum 
WHERE users_len > 0
```

but it doesn't work :'(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT length(users) AS users_len
   , auto_reply_users
FROM forum
HAVING users_len > 0
```

Comment: @hah If this answer is correct, please click the ckeck mark near the answer to accept.  This will remove the question from the unanaswered list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about having without group by. I would rather use usual and expected form

```
SELECT length(users) as users_len,
       auto_reply_users 
FROM forum 
WHERE length(users) > 0
```

I guess profiler wont execute length twice, but I might be mistaken about that.